# Error al usar JSON.parse: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 3101"

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web de un test y tengo un archivo JSON con las preguntas, pero tengo un error al intentar convertir el archivo JSON a un objeto de javascript usando la función `JSON.parse()`.

Aquí está el código:

```
function escogerPregunta (numero) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 200) { 
            respuestaJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //Aqui está el error
            console.log(respuestaJSON);

            /*
            var p = respuestaJSON.preguntas[numero].pregunta;
            var r = respuestaJSON.preguntas[numero].respuestas;
            var s = '';
            s += '<h1>' + p + '</h1>';
            for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                s += '<input name="opciones" type=radio id="' + i + '">';
                s += '<label for="' + i + '">' + r[i] + '</label><br>';      
            }
            $('#pregunta').innerHTML = s;
            $('#pregunta').hide().fadeIn(700);
            radios[0].checked = 'checked';
            */
        }
        else {
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/quiz/data.json', true);
    xhr.send(null);    
}
```

Y aquí está el archivo JSON:

```
{
    "preguntas": [{
            "pregunta": "¿Cuál es la montaña más alta del mundo?",
            "respuestas": ["Kijimanjaro", "Monte Everest", "Makalu"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 1
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Quién vivía en el 221B de Backer Street?",
            "respuestas": ["Sherlock Holmes", "Truman Capote", "Philip Marlowe", "Arthur Conan Doyle"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 0
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿En que año descubrió Colón América?",
            "respuestas": ["1502", "1492", "1946", "1488"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 1
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿En qué año se estrenó la película de Disney <q>Pinocho</q>?",
            "respuestas": ["1940", "1950", "1952", "1946"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 0
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Quién descubrió el ADN?",
            "respuestas": ["Tristan Tzara", "Alfred Jarry", "James Watson y Francis Crick", "Friedrich Miescher"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 2
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿De que deporte es el kemari uno de los principales antecesores?",
            "respuestas": ["Fútbol", "Ténis", "Rugby", "Karate"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 0
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cuál es la capital de Brasil",
            "respuestas": ["Sao Paulo", "Brasilia", "Río de Janeiro"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 1
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cómo se llama el protagonista de <q>El código Da Vinci<q/> de Dan Brown?",
            "respuestas": ["Robert Langdom", "Tom Hanks", "Mr. White", "Robert Black"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 0
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿En que guerra participó Juana de Arco?",
            "respuestas": ["La guerra de los 30 años", "La guerra de los 100 años", "Guerras napoleónicas"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 1
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cómo se llamaba el personaje que interpretaba Al Pacino en Scarface?",
            "respuestas": ["Sonny Montana", "Tony Montana", "Michael Corleone", "Frank Slade"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 1
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "Quién fue el primero en decir que la tierra gira alrededor del sol?",
            "respuestas": ["Copérnico", "Galileo", "Aristarco de Samos", "Kepler"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 2
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cuántas finales del mundo jugó la Selección Argentina de fútbol?",
            "respuestas": ["Cinco", "Seis", "Cuatro", "Tres"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 2
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cuál es el segundo continente más grande del mundo?",
            "respuestas": ["África", "Antártida", "Norte América", "Europa"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 0
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cómo se llama a la gente que no posee magia en la saga de Harry Potter?",
            "respuestas": ["Humano", "Simplón", "Impuro", "Muggles"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 3
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿En que país nació Adolf Hitler?",
            "respuestas": ["Polonia", "Austria", "Alemania", "Suiza"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 1
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Qué grupo interpretaba la canción <q>Smells like teen spirit</q>?",
            "respuestas": ["Los Beatles", "Led Zeppelin", "Nirvana", "Los Rolling Stones"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 2
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Qué órgano del cuerpo humano produce la bilis?",
            "respuestas": ["Hígado", "Páncreas", "Intestino delgado", "Riñon"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 0
        },
        {
            "pregunta": "¿Cuántos jugadores componen un equipo de rugby?",
            "respuestas": ["11", "12", "15", "21"],
            "respuesta_correcta": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Google chrome me dice que es un error de sintaxis, pero no veo dónde está dicho error. Intenté borrar esta línea de código y el error desaparece `respuestaJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

La consola de google chrome da este error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 3101
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Comment: Si los datos ya están en formato JSON no tienes porque usar JSON.parse() simplemente asignas el objeto a la variable `respuestaJSON = xhr.responseText;`

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes? He intentado reproducir el problema y no me sale ningún tipo de error, me vuelca el contenido del JSON correctamente a la consola, `preguntas` como un array de 18 objetos (`Object preguntas: Array[18] ...`). ¿Tu archivo JSON está en UTF-8 o ISO-8859-*? He probado a simular lo que pasaría con ISO y simplemente salen caracteres extraños, pero me sigue funcionando..

Comment: No hay ningún `";"` en el JSON que publicaste. Por favor publica el mismo texto que estás recibiendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El fallo puede ser porque estás intentando convertir a JSON un archivo que ya es JSON, es decir, el método `json.parse(string)` lo que hace es convertir un String a JSON, pero si le pasas un objeto que ya es de tipo JSON va a dar el error que se te reproduce a ti. Intenta hacer el mismo código pero sin parsear el JSON, algo así:

```
function escogerPregunta (numero) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) { 
        respuestaJSON = xhr.responseText; //Así
        console.log(respuestaJSON);

        /*
        var p = respuestaJSON.preguntas[numero].pregunta;
        var r = respuestaJSON.preguntas[numero].respuestas;
        var s = '';
        s += '<h1>' + p + '</h1>';
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            s += '<input name="opciones" type=radio id="' + i + '">';
            s += '<label for="' + i + '">' + r[i] + '</label><br>';      
        }
        $('#pregunta').innerHTML = s;
        $('#pregunta').hide().fadeIn(700);
        radios[0].checked = 'checked';
        */
    }
    else {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/quiz/data.json', true);
xhr.send(null);    
}
```

Comment: Si te das cuenta no usó el botón de bloque de código, por lo que esa llave quedó fuera de la zona remarcada en gris. Lo he corregido, no es el problema.

Comment: sí, lo siento no lo había visto ahora lo edito.

Comment: ¿Ese código lo has probado? Lo que se vuelca a la consola es una cadena de texto (multilínea), y no un objeto.

Comment: @OscarGarcia no puedo probarlo ahora mismo, que no tengo un servidor web para alojar el json, pero varias veces me surgieron problemas así por lo mismo, lo pongo por si le puede resultar de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te falto agregar esto.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Debe ir vaya después del xhr.open();

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/post', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhr.onload = function() {
          // tu código
        }
```

Ademas tu respuesta ya esta en json solo debes acceder a los atributos.

Comment: ¿Has reproducido tu código para ver si soluciona el problema planteado? Esa línea que has introducido no altera en nada la respuesta, se usa para [cambiar las cabeceras enviadas al servidor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader), esa en particular para indicar al servidor el formato en el que se envían los datos (generalmente por `post`).